# Change date format in webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the following code to display a last updated date on my webpage.
The problem is the format is in MM/DD/YYYY but I need DD/MM/YYYY to be there.

In HEAD :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
onload = function()
{
document.getElementById("lastModified").innerHTML = "Last updated :  " + 
document.lastModified.split(" ")[0];
}
</script>
```

In body

```
<span id="lastModified"></span>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `toLocaleDateString()` to format your date

```js
onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("lastModified").innerHTML = "Last updated :  " +
    new Date(document.lastModified).toLocaleDateString('in');
}
```

```html
<span id="lastModified"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can covert `document.lastModified` to a `Date` object, then get all the relevant data for your date using the `Date` object's methods such as `getDate()`, `getMonth()` and `getFullYear()`. Then merge all these components into a string to form a full date.

See example below:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let lastMod = new Date(document.lastModified);
  let day = lastMod.getDate();
  let month = lastMod.getMonth();
  let year = lastMod.getFullYear();
  let lastModStr = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
  document.getElementById("lastModified").textContent = "Last updated :  " + lastModStr;
}
```

```html
<span id="lastModified"></span>
```